# How to chain methods in a List

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I have a list containing Actions, and I want to chain them together, how should I go about it?

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => factory.AllTheMethodsInActions));
```

Here is this I go about it without being using a list:

```
_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => factory.Resize(_currentSize).Rotate(_currentDegrees).Flip(_currentFlipVertically))
```

Is this possible at all? Would it be possible to "Add" the methods instead? Pseudo-code

```
Action original = () => _imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => factory.Resize(_currentSize));
Action toAdd = () => Rotate(_currentDegrees);
Action newAction = original + toAdd
// Result would look like this //
_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => factory.Resize(_currentSize).Rotate(_currentDegrees));
```

Here's the rest of the code that might be useful:

```
public Image ProcessImage(Image image, Func<ImageFactory, ImageFactory> process)
    {
        using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))
        {
            using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var loadResult = imageFactory.Load(image);
                var processResult = process(loadResult.agg);
                processResult.Save(imageStream);

                return Image.FromStream(imageStream);
            }
        }
    }

public void Resize(Size size)
    {
        _currentSize = size;

        // SCALE _image and fire event:
        OnImageChanged(_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => factory.Resize(_currentSize)));
    }

public void Rotate(int degrees)
    {
        _currentDegrees = degrees;

        // Rotate _image and fire event:
        OnImageChanged(_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => factory.Rotate(_currentDegrees)));
    }
```

Comment: What is a type of variable *factory*? What types does methods *Resize*, *Rotate* and *Flip* return?

Comment: If you can chain methods like that then it isn't a `List<Action>`. It's going to be more like `Func<Image, Image>`. Can you please post a [mcve] with real code?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev factory is a ImageFactory (ImageProcessor library). The methods return an image

Comment: I'm using them with an event like:
OnImageChanged(_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => factory.Resize(_currentSize)));

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You told that methods `Rotate`, `Resize` and `Flip` in the code snippet `_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => factory.Resize(_currentSize).Rotate(_currentDegrees).Flip(_currentFlipVertically))` have return type of type `Image`. But in the last code snippet this methods return `void`. Also I think that `List<Action> actions` should contain delegates of type `Func<ImageFactory, ImageFactory>` instead of `Action`. Could you share also code that shows how you form list `List<Action> actions`.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev I'm sorry, that was my bad, but it returns an image that I then use in the "OnImageChanged" event that will update my image in the UI. I've now changed the list to Func<Image, Image>, check the answer I posted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest you can convert each Action to Func

Then you can have the following format. This is a generic version considering not every chained step returns the same type of instance:

```
var actions=new List<Func<object,object>>[]{ 
    (input, output)=> { (input as FactoryType).Resize(_currentSize); return input},
    (input, output)=> { (input as FactoryType).Rotate(_currentDegrees); return output}
};

// TODO: Add more steps here individually

_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => {
    object input=factory;
    foreach( var action in actions)
    {
        input=action.Invoke(input);
    }
});
```

The foreach loop can also be converted to IEnumerable.Aggregate calls, like

```
_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, factory => {
    actions.Aggregate<Func<object,object>,object,object>(factory, (input, step)=>{input=step(input)}, input=>input);
    });
```

If you are sure every step will output the result of the same type as the input type, then we can narrow down the type from object to your customized FactoryType in your actions definitions.

Comment: The OP has told us that the type is `Func<ImageFactory, ImageFactory>`, so why use `Func<object, object>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity, 'coz it was added later

Comment: I've only accepted this answer since it helped me understand how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I was looking for but I found a decent way to go about this problem. I'll keep the other answer as the accepted one but this might be useful for someone else.

```
    List<Func<Image, Image>> _currentEditFuncs;

    public void Rotate(int degrees)
    {
        _currentDegrees = degrees;

        AddNewFunc((image) => _imageEditor.ProcessImage(image, factory => factory.Rotate(_currentDegrees)));
    }

    void AddNewFunc(Func<Image, Image> newEditFunc)
    {
        bool containsAction = _currentEditFuncs.Contains(newEditFunc);

        if (!containsAction)
        {
            _currentEditFuncs.Add(newEditFunc);
        }
    }

    Image ApplyEdits()
    {
        // Declare the image to be edited (using the original):
        Image newImage = _image;

        // Loop through the current edit functions and apply them to the newImage:
        _currentEditFuncs.ForEach(action => newImage = action.Invoke(newImage));

        return newImage;
    }

    void EditImage()
    {
        // Fire the event that updates the image passing the method that applies the edits:
        OnImageChanged(ApplyEdits());
    }
```